# sklearn - Как построить простой конвеер Pipeline для набора данных?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

*Описание*: сижу на Kaggle на задаче SS Titanic, **метки** в наборе данных **представлены** **как Boolean тип**, поэтому **нужно их превратить в числовой тип (1-0)**. Это я сделал просто напрямую работая с колонкой датафрейма пандаса (Код №1), но ведь это неправильно, нужно сделать конвееры, чтобы потом передавать быстро и эффективно новый набор данных сразу в конвеер.

Пример конвеера беру из книги, но там не очень всё понятно. Вроде как можно создать класс, используя его потом в качестве "ячейки" конвеера, а вроде можно и функцию использовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

*Вопрос*: как **сделать** простой **конвеер**, который бы делал замену Boolean меток на числовой тип (1-0)?

```
# Код №1.
dataset["labels"] = dataset["labels"].map(lambda a: 1 if a == True else 0)
```

```
# Код №2.
dataset_pipeline = Pipeline([
    () # Всё действо как понимаю происходит тут.
    ])

dataset_pipeline.fit_transform(dataset)
```

Comment: [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies) случаем не то что Вы ищете? С ним можно не только True False преобразовывать, и если dataset небольшой, то нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы в pandas делать. По pipeline [тут](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pandas-data-pipelines-515bcc678570) есть хороший урок. По сути оборачиваете получение данных и преобразование в функции, в Pipeline засовываете название шага, функцию и пустые kwargs через `{}`.

Comment: @DiMithras, не важно мне большой или маленький набор данных, это глаз режет, когда нужно будет применять функцию каждый раз по отдельности для нового набора данных. И таких функций несколько. Ужас!!!!!! >:( . А урок по вашей ссылке не очень подходит, там какая-то доп. библиотека используется с гитхаба, некрасиво получается.

Comment: @DiMithras, проблема решена, спасибо : )

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена с помощью функции sklearn **FunctionTransformer**, которая помогает вам преобразовать вашу функцию для использования её в Pipeline.

Мне помог этот ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429857/16010182